# Why does a div with ::after selector position itself inside the original div in CSS

Tags: css

Let's take the following example:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

The problem I faced, is that the first div get positioned inside the second one as you can see in this image:
[image]

How can I fix this problem to have the original div (the red one) followed by the div with the ::after selector (the green div)

Comment: They are not getting "positioned over each other", one is _inside_ the other. And if you put a (pseudo-)element with width:200px and height:250px into another element with those exact same dimensions, you can hardly expect a different result.

Comment: hello, pseudos are virtual and created inside their parent. ::before means before any content that stands in that container and ::after right after any content. they are themselves content of that element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent div's position to relative, set the after pseudo element's position to absolute, and set it's left to 100% so that it'll start from the right side of it's parent container(red div)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">f</div>
```